# PackageManager not installing app

Tags: android, installation, package-managers, su

I have Android tablets that are rooted.  I use SuperUser to execute PackageManager to install updates occasionally as necessary.

Recently however, the updates stopped installing on the tablets.  Research shows that the process returns a successful install response:

```
apk = apkName;

String command = "pm install -r "+apkDirectory+apkName +" \n";
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());  
os.writeBytes(command);  
os.writeBytes("exit\n"); 
os.flush();
InputStream stdin = process.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = null;
Log.d("OTAApp", "Install output..");
StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null){
    strBuffer.append(line);
}
Log.d("OTAApp", strBuffer.toString());

int exitVal = process.waitFor();

Log.d("OTAApp", "Installing done for: "+apkName+"... process exitValue: "+ exitVal);

Log.d("OTAApp", "All Installs done");
```

Logcat:

```
06-02 09:30:26.523: D/OTAApp(12439): Now Installing short...
06-02 09:30:26.593: D/OTAApp(12439): Install output..
06-02 09:30:27.484: D/OTAApp(12439): Installing done for: short.apk... process exitValue: 0
06-02 09:30:27.484: D/OTAApp(12439): launching short...
06-02 09:30:27.744: D/OTAApp(12439): All Installs done
```

**What could possibly be happening here?**  No OS updates have been applied to the tablets.  The tablets are Verizon branded Samsung SCH-i705 LTE.  The OS is Android 4.1.2.  As stated earlier, the tablets are root and the software calling SU has root permissions and should be able to install apps.

Any help is very much appreciated?